# How can I get the primitive name of a type in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to print out a method signature, e.g.

```
foreach (var pi in mi.GetParameters()) {
    Console.WriteLine(pi.Name + ": " + pi.ParameterType.ToString());
}
```

This works pretty well, but it prints out the type of primitives as "System.String" instead of "string" and "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]" instead of "int?". Is there a way to get the name of the parameter as it looks in code, e.g.

```
public Example(string p1, int? p2)
```

prints

```
p1: string
p2: int?
```

instead of

```
p1: System.String
p2: System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a type's alias through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection)

Answer (score 38):

EDIT: I was half wrong in the answer below.

Have a look at [`CSharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.gettypeoutput.aspx). Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        // Just to prove a point...
        var type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Int32));
        Console.WriteLine(compiler.GetTypeOutput(type)); // Prints int
    }
}
```

However, this *doesn't* translate `Nullable<T>` into `T?` - and I can't find any options which would make it do so, although that doesn't mean such an option doesn't exist :)

---

There's nothing in the framework to support this - after all, they're C#-specific names.

(Note that `string` *isn't* a [primitive type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx), by the way.)

You'll have to do it by spotting `` Nullable`1 `` yourself ([`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype) may be used for this, for example), and have a map from the full framework name to each alias.

Comment: `CSharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput` doesn't change `System.String` to `string` though.

Comment: it does here now too... I should have known better :-) oh, and I posted that before your code was up

Comment: Unforunately it does not work with "out" parameters of methods :( I

Comment: @JonSkeet In my case I ended up with something like `(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType) != null ? compiler.GetTypeOutput(new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType))) + "?" : compiler.GetTypeOutput(new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(p.ParameterType)))`, using the original type to check for nullable

Comment: Also, should the CSharpCodeProvider be wrapped in a using statement? Seeing as it's IDisposable

Comment: @DennisvanGils: I believe that's just inherited from `Component`. I suspect that in most cases it's fine not to dispose it - but it wouldn't hurt to do so.

Comment: @Mic: If you want it to work with in/out/ref params, run it through a pass of `if (type.HasElementType) type = type.GetElementType();` first (you may want to give array types special treatment here, though). If you're also resolving nullables, do that *before* `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`.

Answer (score 4):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1362884/119477) has two interesting answers. The [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection/1362899#1362899) from Jon Skeet <strike>pretty much says what he said already.</strike>

**EDIT**
Jon updated his answer so its pretty much the same as mine is now. (But of course 20 secs earlier)

But Luke H also gives [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection/1363309#1363309) which I thought was pretty awesome use of the CodeDOM.

```
Type t = column.DataType;    // Int64

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    var expr = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(t);

    var prov = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    prov.GenerateCodeFromExpression(expr, sw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());    // long
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most beautiful code in the world, but this is what I ended up doing:
(building on Cornard's code)

```
public static string CSharpName(this Type type)
{
    if (!type.FullName.StartsWith("System"))
        return type.Name;
    var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var t = new CodeTypeReference(type);
    var output = compiler.GetTypeOutput(t);
    output = output.Replace("System.","");
    if (output.Contains("Nullable<"))
        output = output.Replace("Nullable","").Replace(">","").Replace("<","") + "?";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: warning! doesn't work with nested generics as `<` and `>` are blindly replaced

Answer (score 1):

Another option, based on the other answers here.

Features:

- Convert `String` to `string` and `Int32` to `int` etc
- Deal with `Nullable<Int32>` as `int?` etc
- Suppress `System.DateTime` to be `DateTime`
- All other types are written in full

It deals with the simple cases I needed, not sure if it will handle complex types well..

```
Type type = /* Get a type reference somehow */
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
{
    return compiler.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type.GetGenericArguments()[0])).Replace("System.","") + "?";
}
else
{
    return compiler.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type)).Replace("System.","");
}
```

Comment: Its been a loooong time, but I beleive it is: `var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();`

Comment: There are much simpler ways to get the nullable type: https://pastebin.com/evjr4Umh

Answer (score 0):

No. `string` is just a representation of `System.String` -- `string` doesn't really mean anything behind the scenes.

By the way, to get past `System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]`, you can use  `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);`

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I came up with after ~5 mins of hacking.  For example:

```
CSharpAmbiance.GetTypeName(typeof(IDictionary<string,int?>))
```

will return `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, int?>`.

```
public static class CSharpAmbiance
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, string> aliases =
        new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    static CSharpAmbiance()
    {
        aliases[typeof(byte)] = "byte";
        aliases[typeof(sbyte)] = "sbyte";
        aliases[typeof(short)] = "short";
        aliases[typeof(ushort)] = "ushort";
        aliases[typeof(int)] = "int";
        aliases[typeof(uint)] = "uint";
        aliases[typeof(long)] = "long";
        aliases[typeof(ulong)] = "ulong";
        aliases[typeof(char)] = "char";

        aliases[typeof(float)] = "float";
        aliases[typeof(double)] = "double";

        aliases[typeof(decimal)] = "decimal";

        aliases[typeof(bool)] = "bool";

        aliases[typeof(object)] = "object";
        aliases[typeof(string)] = "string";
    }

    private static string RemoveGenericNamePart(string name)
    {
        int backtick = name.IndexOf('`');

        if (backtick != -1)
            name = name.Substring(0, backtick);

        return name;
    }

    public static string GetTypeName(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        string keyword;
        if (aliases.TryGetValue(type, out keyword))
            return keyword;

        if (type.IsArray) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var ranks = new Queue<int>();
            do {
                ranks.Enqueue(type.GetArrayRank() - 1);
                type = type.GetElementType();
            } while (type.IsArray);

            sb.Append(GetTypeName(type));

            while (ranks.Count != 0) {
                sb.Append('[');

                int rank = ranks.Dequeue();
                for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
                    sb.Append(',');

                sb.Append(']');
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append(RemoveGenericNamePart(type.FullName));
            sb.Append('<');

            var args = type.GetGenericArguments().Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < args; i++)
                sb.Append(',');

            sb.Append('>');

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType) {
            if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                return GetTypeName(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]) + "?";

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append(RemoveGenericNamePart(type.FullName));
            sb.Append('<');

            var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
                if (i != 0)
                    sb.Append(", ");

                sb.Append(GetTypeName(args[i]));
            }

            sb.Append('>');

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        return type.FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about arrays? Should a two-dimensional array of int be "int[,]" or "System.Int32[,]", or what?

Comment: @Eric: Oops, forgot about array types.  I have updated the method to handle them.

Comment: Your code is now wrong for ragged array types. Remember, an int[,][] is a two-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays, not a one-dimensional array of two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Eric: Ah, yes, one of the reasons I hate C# array syntax.  One would expect `int[,][]` to mean `(int[,])[]`...

Comment: See my article on the subject for an explanation of why it is this way: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx

Comment: @Eric: Are you trying to make a point or do you actually want to see the code improved?

Comment: Both. If you're going to proffer a solution to a problem then it's worthwhile to actually solve the stated problem, and actively harmful to provide a half-baked solution that solves the stated problem wrong in many cases. The larger point is that your design methodology leaves much to be desired; rather than writing a bad solution and then adding a patch every time someone finds a bug, write a spec that considers all the cases *first* and then code to the spec.

Comment: Some of the other cases you've forgotten, incidentally, are pointer types, out/ref types, and the fact that System.Void is aliased as "void".

Comment: @Eric: And you didn't tell me that initially why?  P.S. Still waiting for your solution.

Comment: @Eric: I guess my point is that you could have said that right away and saved a lot of pointless re-coding.  I would rather have you be up-front with your criticism than drag me through a bunch of pointless exercises -- you are not my professor, so please don't act like you are.  My answer has been community-wikified.  Feel free to direct some of your energy into improving it if you would like.

Comment: Because the dialectical method is a highly effective pedagogic technique. I don't think it was pointless re-coding if you, or someone else, learned something valuable from it. My solution is not forthcoming; a correct solution would take me at least half the day to write and test and I don't have that kind of time.

Comment: @Eric: It's also incredibly condescending if we are not in an existing student-teacher relationship.

Comment: @cdhowie: Keep in mind he's trying to teach anyone else who reads this in the future as well, so is probably not a simple attempt at a personal insult.

Comment: @asawyer: I'm not saying it was an *attempt* to insult, only that it is a rather insulting approach without any preexisting relationship between us.

Comment: @asawyer: It is not any kind of attempt at any kind of insult, personal or otherwise. It's extremely constructive and well-meant feedback on a deeply flawed answer to a reasonable technical question. This is a collaberatively edited site which seeks to provide accurate answers to technical questions; constructive feedback is by design a part of that.