# Why 'typeof(string).FullName' is giving 'System.String' and not 'string'?

Tags: c#, types, typeof

Why `typeof(string).FullName` is giving `System.String` and not `string`? The same is with all other "simple" types like `int`, `float`, `double`, ...

I understand that `typeof` is returning the `System.Type` object for the given type, but why is `string` not also be an `System.Type` object ?

Is it because `string` is part of the c# language, and `System.Type`is part of the system libraries?

Comment: It is because `string` is an alias for the `System.String` class which is sitting in the `System` namespace. If you use `typeof(string).Name` you get only the classname `String`.

Comment: In addition to _Tim Schmelter_'s comment above: The same can be said for the primitives: `typeof(int).FullName` will return `int`, but `typeof(Int32).FullName` will return `System.Int32`. System.`String` and `string` are exactly the same, and are used based on preference. I personally use `string` for fields, and `String` for static methods/constants, like `String.Empty` or `String.Format(...)`. I always thought they were EXACTLY the same in everything, but apparently their type-FullName are also different. So thanks for this question, because now I've also learned something new. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `string` is an alias for `System.String`. Your `string` C# code is converted on compile time to `System.String`. This is the same for [other aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/993547).

Comment: So there is no difference in Speed between them? I thought System.Type is more 'complex' ?

Comment: Nope. `string` is `System.String` for the full 100%.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, `string` is just an alias for `System.String`, so both are the same and  `typeof` returns the same type object.

The same goes for all other primitive types. For example, `int` is just an alias for `System.Int32`.

If you need to get the shorter C# alias name of a type, you can use `CSharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput()` instead of `FullName`:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;

[...]

var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Int32));
Console.WriteLine(compiler.GetTypeOutput(type)); // Prints int
```

(code snippet taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369737/how-can-i-get-the-primitive-name-of-a-type-in-c))

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but is the creation of an CSharpCodeProvider not 'to expensive' for this, specially if you do it often?

Comment: I did not measure it, but if you need to do this very often, I would suggest to cache the c# names in a `Dictionary<Type,string>` or something like that. If you need the name, look it up in the dictionary. If it is not in it, perform the slow `GetTypeOutput` and save it in the dictionary.

Comment: 10.000 tries took 11ms on my end. So performance is not an issue.