# C#, Reflection and primitive types

Tags: c#, reflection, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the primitive name of a type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369737/how-can-i-get-the-primitive-name-of-a-type-in-c)

I have the following code in C#:

```
        Assembly sysAssembly = 0.GetType().Assembly;
        Type[] sysTypes = sysAssembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type sysType in sysTypes)
        {
            if (sysType.IsPrimitive && sysType.IsPublic)
                Console.WriteLine(sysType.Name);
        }
```

This code outputs:

> Boolean, Byte, Char, Double, Int16, Int32, Int64, IntPtr, SByte,
>   Single, UInt16,  UInt32, UInt64, UIntPtr,

I would like to replace `Boolean` by `bool`, `Byte` by `byte` and so on when possible, without relying on a fixed array or dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate to

[C# - Get user-friendly name of simple types through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615553/c-sharp-get-user-friendly-name-of-simple-types-through-reflection)

This is a good answer by Skeet, too

[How can I get the primitive name of a type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369737/how-can-i-get-the-primitive-name-of-a-type-in-c)

The answer is, YOU CAN, and without a dictionary.

```
Type t = typeof(bool);

string typeName;
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
  var typeRef = new CodeTypeReference(t);
  typeName = provider.GetTypeOutput(typeRef);
}

Console.WriteLine(typeName);    // bool
```