# Create any type instance from its string via reflection

Tags: c#, string, reflection, casting

Imagine the following scenario:

A user passes a string to the application, which represents a .NET-Type, e.g. `string` or `System.IntPtr`. Assuming, that the application in question has access to the assemblies, in which the given Types are defined, it can create an instance of the given type based on the string.

I have managed to create such an application; the problem is only, that I am not (yet) able to create *"complex"* or *"nested"* types, e.g.:

- Generics like `System.Tuple<string, System.Action>`
- Arrays of `T` like `int[]`, `System.IntPtr[]`, etc...
- Pointer of `T` like `int*`, `char**`, `Namespace.MyStruct*`, etc...
- Any (possible) combination of the cases above

**My question is:** How can I create such nested type instances, when only given the string representation of the type (and of course all required assemblies)?

Do the .NET BCL contain some sort of `string --> Type`-parser? Or do I have to use some form of recursive regex-parser and `Activator.CreateInstance`?

---

**EDIT №1:**

As this question seems to be too broad, I will try to clarify myself:

I am able to create type instances for 'simple' types - I am, however, struggling to create type instances of 'complex' types, e.g.:

```
Type t1 = typeof(string).Assembly.GetType("System.String");
Type t2 = typeof(string).Assembly.GetType("System.Tuple<System.String, System.Int32>");
object obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(t1);
object obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(t2);
```

`obj1` is an instance of `string`, but `obj2` will fail, as the variable `t2` is `null` (Meaning, that the second line in the given code was unable to find the 'complex' type).

---

**EDIT №2:**

The usage of [`Type::MakeGenericType(Type[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) is obviously helpful, but how would be the easiest/fastest(?) way to create an instance of a type like this:

`IEnumerable<Tuple<int[,], char[][], Dictionary<string, Func<int, int*, byte>>>>`

I would have to write some kind of regex-based parser, which iterates recursively over the different sections of the given string....

---

**EDIT №3:**

I have discovered [`System::CodeDom::CodeTypeReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference(v=vs.110).aspx) and I am currently searching for a method to get the type based on a given `CodeTypeReference`-instance (which can be created using the type's string representation).

---

**EDIT №4:** *(sorry for all the edits)*

I think I found my solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16987213/3902603).

Comment: I didn't vote to close this question because, although there may be tons of ways to do this (so it's Too Broad) there is also built-in BCL methods of doing it pretty standardly, so I think it's actually beneficial to SO to have a question about this.

Comment: @Jeff: I edited my question.... Do you think, that it is OK? If not, how should I edit it to better match SO's guidelines? :)

Comment: Well, as I said, I thought the question was ok as it was. Having said that, feel free to answer your own question, since it looks like you found a better solution

Comment: @Jeff: I am not yet going to answer my question (I will probably in a few days), as I want to give other users the chance to answer ..... and because I have found some issues with my current solution :)

Comment: Just a tip (doesn't sound like you're doing it anyway but still) you won't want to use a regex based parser, because generic types are not regex (nested brackets are a dead giveaway)

Comment: @Jeff: Could you please elaborate this a little bit further, Sir? I do not (yet) quite understand, what you mean with `...generic types are not regex`. Do you mean, that it will be difficult to parse the type string?

Comment: The language of generic types is not regular. Look up context sensitive and context free languages if you're interested, it's too much for me to explain here sorry

Comment: @Jeff: Ah ok -- I now see what you mean, Sir. I will do some more resarch :)

Comment: @Jeff: I added a (small) answer, in which I described how I parsed nested types --- in case you were interested ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing :-) don't forget that you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Jeff: I know that I can accept it, but I will not do it yet.... at least until I have found a better solution

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but it looks like you're looking for [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx). Specifically, the [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The documentation states the following about this method:

> Gets the Type with the specified name, performing a case-sensitive search.

Then you will want to look at [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

> Creates an instance of the specified type using that type's default constructor

Before you create the instance for generic types, though, you'll be wanting to look at [`Type.MakeGenericType'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Substitutes the elements of an array of types for the type parameters of the current generic type definition and returns a Type object representing the resulting constructed type.

You might find the answers to this other question useful too: [How to use Activator to create an instance of a generic Type and casting it back to that type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9140873/781965)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it (temporarily) as follows:

1. Check if the given string contains `<` or `>`
2. If so, parse the string according to the function given below (`ParseGeneric`) and continue recursively using the parsed tokens
3. If not, check for any occurrence of array brackets (`[]`, `[][]`, `[,]` etc.)
4. Parse the type accordingly using a recursive `Array::CreateInstance(Type,int[])`
5. Check for any occurrence of pointer 'stars' (`*`) and parse the type accordingly using `Marshal::StructureToPtr`

---

My `ParseGeneric`-method:

```
public static Type FetchGenericType(string typestring)
{
    Match m;

    if ((m = Regex.Match(typestring, )).Success)
    {
        string cls = m.Groups["class"].ToString();
        string par = m.Groups["params"].Success ? m.Groups["params"].ToString() : "";

        List<string> paramtypes = new List<string>();
        int s = 0, e = 0;

        for (int i = 0, c = 0, l = par.Length; i < l; i++)
            switch (par[i])
            {
                case ',':
                    if (c > 0)
                        goto default;

                    paramtypes.Add(par.Substring(s, e));

                    s = i + 1;
                    e = 0;
                    break;
                case '<': ++c;
                    goto default;
                case '>': --c;
                    goto default;
                default: ++e;
                    break;
            } // I know, that this is bad as hell, but what should I do instead?

        paramtypes.Add(par.Substring(s, e));

        IEnumerable<Type> @params = from type in paramtypes
                                    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type)
                                    select FetchGenericType(type);

        string paramstring = string.Join(", ", from type in @params select "[" + type.FullName + ", " + type.Assembly.GetName().Name + "]");
        string result = @params.Count() == 0 ? cls : string.Format("{0}`{1}[{2}]", cls, @paramsCount(), paramstr);

        // The string has now the format '...List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]'
        // or: 'System.Tuple[[System.Int32, mscorlib], [System.Object, mscorlib]]' ...
        return FetchType(result);
    }
    else
        return FetchType(typestring);
}
```

The function `FetchType` does some basic array bracket parsing and then fetches the type based on the resulted string by looking through the given assemblies.