# Data type of one class to other class using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a class

```
namespace MyNamespace1
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyName { get; set; }
        public int? MaxHeaderLength { get; set; }
        public System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass.ViewModel> Preferences { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace2
{
    internal class myClass1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var properties = loading assembly of the MyClass of MyNamespace1
            var prop = properties.GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in prop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to read the property at the runtime using reflection

I am getting types as

> System.String,
>
> System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,
>   System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]),

But I want to retrieve as

```
string,

int?,

System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass.ViewModel>
```

Can anybody please provide me the solution.

Comment: You want the *friendly name*. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466380/get-user-friendly-name-for-generic-type-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615553/c-sharp-get-user-friendly-name-of-simple-types-through-reflection

Answer (score 0):

`string`, `int?` and `List<MyClass.ViewModel>` are all C# constructs. They're not in .NET itself.

So you simply have to build a lookup table or a giant `switch` to convert the type names to .NET keywords.