# Get all types of properties for an object

Tags: c#

I have an object with some types of properties:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<SomeObj> List { get; set; }
    public int SomeKey { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

var obj = new MyClass();
```

What is the best way to get all types of properties for `obj` instance of the `MyClass` ?
For example:

```
obj.GetAllPropertiesTypes() //int, string, List<>
obj.HasPropertyType("int")  //True
```

Comment: obj.GetType().GetProperties();

Answer (score 2):

Using Reflection:

```
var obj = new MyClass();

foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name = {prop.Name} ** Type = { prop.PropertyType}");
}
```

Result:

```
Name = List ** Type = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NameSpaceSample.SomeObj]
Name = SomeKey ** Type = System.Int32
Name = SomeString ** Type = System.String
```

If you're looking for more **user-friendly** type names, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4615640/3185569).

As for Has property of a specific type, then:

```
bool hasInt = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Any(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(int));
```