# GetType return Int instead of System.Int32

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

GetType().ToString() returns the FullName of the object. I want the name that you usually use to instantiate that object, i.e, int instead of Int32. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why? anyway you cant... You will have to build a *Dictionary* and map them over yourself. There is no *reflection* way to get a type *alias*... eg `int` instead of `Int32`, as `Int32` is the actual *type* not `int` which is the *alias*

Comment: It's worth noting that not all .NET assemblies are written in c#. If yours wasn't, the variable of interest may not have been declared as an `int`, which is a c# keyword (in Visual Basic it is `Integer`, for example). The string `Int32` is the .NET name for the type agnostic of language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C# has a number of 'types' that are actually keyword aliases to .NET CLR `Type`s.  In this case, `int` is a C# alias for `System.Int32`, but the same is true of other C# types like `string` which is an alias to `System.String`.

This means that when you get under the hood with reflection and start looking at the CLR `Type` objects you won't find `int`, `string` or any of the other C# type aliases because .NET and the CLR don't know about them... and nor should they.

If you want to translate from the CLR type to a C# alias you'll have to do it yourself via lookup.  Something like this:

```
// This is the set of types from the C# keyword list.
static Dictionary<Type, string> _typeAlias = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    { typeof(bool), "bool" },
    { typeof(byte), "byte" },
    { typeof(char), "char" },
    { typeof(decimal), "decimal" },
    { typeof(double), "double" },
    { typeof(float), "float" },
    { typeof(int), "int" },
    { typeof(long), "long" },
    { typeof(object), "object" },
    { typeof(sbyte), "sbyte" },
    { typeof(short), "short" },
    { typeof(string), "string" },
    { typeof(uint), "uint" },
    { typeof(ulong), "ulong" },
    // Yes, this is an odd one.  Technically it's a type though.
    { typeof(void), "void" }
};

static string TypeNameOrAlias(Type type)
{
    // Lookup alias for type
    if (_typeAlias.TryGetValue(type, out string alias))
        return alias;

    // Default to CLR type name
    return type.Name;
}
```

For simple types that will work fine.  Generics, arrays and `Nullable` take a bit more work.  Arrays and `Nullable` values are handled recursively like this:

```
static string TypeNameOrAlias(Type type)
{
    // Handle nullable value types
    var nullbase = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (nullbase != null)
        return TypeNameOrAlias(nullbase) + "?";

    // Handle arrays
    if (type.BaseType == typeof(System.Array))
        return TypeNameOrAlias(type.GetElementType()) + "[]";

    // Lookup alias for type
    if (_typeAlias.TryGetValue(type, out string alias))
        return alias;

    // Default to CLR type name
    return type.Name;
}
```

This will handle things like:

```
Console.WriteLine(TypeNameOrAlias(typeof(int?[][])));
```

Generics, if you need them, are a bit more involved basically the same process.  Scan through the generic parameter list and run the types recursively through the process.

---

#### Nested Types

When you run `TypeNameOrAlias` on a nested type the result is only the name of the specific type, not the full path you'd need to specify to use it from outside the type that declares it:

```
public class Outer
{
    public class Inner
    {
    }
}
// TypeNameOrAlias(typeof(Outer.Inner)) == "Inner"
```

This resolves the issue:

```
static string GetTypeName(Type type)
{
    string name = TypeNameOrAlias(type);
    if (type.DeclaringType is Type dec)
    {
        return $"{GetTypeName(dec)}.{name}";
    }
    return name;
}
// GetTypeName(typeof(Outer.Inner)) == "Outer.Inner"
```

#### Generics

Generics in the .NET type system are interesting.  It's relatively easy to handle things like `List<int>` or `Dictionary<int, string>` or similar.  Insert this at the top of `TypeNameOrAlias`:

```
    // Handle generic types
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        string name = type.Name.Split('`').FirstOrDefault();
        IEnumerable<string> parms = 
            type.GetGenericArguments()
            .Select(a => type.IsConstructedGenericType ? TypeNameOrAlias(a) : a.Name);
        return $"{name}<{string.Join(",", parms)}>";
    }
```

Now you'll get correct results for things like `TypeNameOrAlias(typeof(Dictionary<int, string>))` and so on.  It also deals with generic type definitions: `TypeNameOrAlias(typeof(Dictionary<,>))` will return `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Where things get difficult is when you nest classes inside generics.  Try `GetTypeName(typeof(Dictionary<int, string>.KeyCollection))` for an interesting result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Why are non simple types handled recursively?

Comment: Recursion is required because you can't know how deep the tree goes before you get to a simple type that you want to alias.  The example `int?[][]` is 3 levels of recursion to get to the `int`.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

This uses [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), handles generics and adds namespaces when required.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
//...
private string GetFriendlyTypeName(Type type)
{
    using (var p = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        var r = new CodeTypeReference(type);
        return p.GetTypeOutput(r);
    }
}
```

Giving [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592598/1477064) where it's due.

Answer (score 3):

```
GetType().ToString().FromDotNetTypeToCSharpType();
```

Using the extension method below. I came up with something similar for some templating I was doing in c# using the following Microsoft reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table

Optionally, a boolean whether the type is nullable can be passed in for the shortcut nullable syntax.

```
    /// <summary>Converts a .Net type name to a C# type name. It will remove the "System." namespace, if present,</summary>
    public static string FromDotNetTypeToCSharpType(this string dotNetTypeName, bool isNull = false)
    {
        string cstype = "";
        string nullable = isNull ? "?" : "";
        string prefix = "System.";
        string typeName = dotNetTypeName.StartsWith(prefix) ? dotNetTypeName.Remove(0, prefix.Length) : dotNetTypeName;

        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "Boolean": cstype = "bool"; break;
            case "Byte":    cstype = "byte"; break;
            case "SByte":   cstype = "sbyte"; break;
            case "Char":    cstype = "char"; break;
            case "Decimal": cstype = "decimal"; break;
            case "Double":  cstype = "double"; break;
            case "Single":  cstype = "float"; break;
            case "Int32":   cstype = "int"; break;
            case "UInt32":  cstype = "uint"; break;
            case "Int64":   cstype = "long"; break;
            case "UInt64":  cstype = "ulong"; break;
            case "Object":  cstype = "object"; break;
            case "Int16":   cstype = "short"; break;
            case "UInt16":  cstype = "ushort"; break;
            case "String":  cstype = "string"; break;

            default: cstype = typeName; break; // do nothing
        }
        return $"{cstype}{nullable}";

    }
```